# problem with (perl) rename recursive stripping special characters in Bash

Tags: bash, character, rename

I'm trying to execute

```
find . -depth -execdir rename 's/\s/./g; s/[^[:alnum:]./]//g' {} +
```

to remove special characters in filenames in Mac Bash shell using (perl) rename.

and getting this message

```
Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[ <-- HERE ^[:alnum:]./ at (eval 2) line 1.
```

Two questions:   a) what is going wrong with the execution  b) how can I modify to insert `_`  character in place of the special characters. Ideally I want to be able to also spot these problem 7 characters as a minimum set but ideally all problem ones (`-  &*$`)   etc

Answer (score 0):

The `/` separates the parts of `s` command. To replace the `/` you have to escape it.

Try:

```
find . -depth -execdir rename 's/\s/./g; s/[^[:alnum:].\/]//g' {} +
```

Comment: I amended slightly:       find . -depth -execdir rename 's/\s/_/g; s/[^[:alnum:].\/]/_/g' {} +

Comment: @KamilCuk : Maybe it would be more clear not to use a `/` as a separator in the first place, but matching parenthesis: `s(...)(...)`